# Jolt Transform Dynamic attribute to Key/Value

Tags: json, jolt

I have a Json file with dynamic attribye depends on "Objets tupes, so i want to get all attributes as Key/Value Pairs.
The input Json :

```
{
  "Boutique": [
    {
      "ID": "1",
      "codePdv": "1000000",
      "codeSav": "1100000",
      "contrats": [
        {
          "_type": "ContratFonds",
          "nomFournisseur": "LOIS"
        },
        {
          "_type": "ContratEau",
          "nomFournisseur": "Veolia",
          "comprisDansLesCharges": false,
          "numeroCompteur": "99Z928"
        },
        {
          "_type": "ContratClimatisation",
          "nomFournisseur": "CLIM"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "ID": "2",
      "codePdv": "2000000",
      "codeSav": "2200000",
      "contrats": [
        {
          "_type": "ContratVideosurveillance",
          "dateDebut": "2020-12-01",
          "dateFin": "2024-12-01",
          "nomFournisseur": "E8MA",
          "dateAutorisationCameras": "2020-12-30",
          "ligneAlarme": "+33188888489",
          "nbCamerasAutorisees": 3
        },
        {
          "_type": "ContratClimatisation",
          "nomFournisseur": "LACLIM"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

and I want to Output like :

```
{
  "pointsDeVente": [
    {
      "ID": "1",
      "codePdv": 1000000,
      "codeSav": 1100000,
      "contrats": [
        {
          "Contrat": [
            {
              "Key": "_type",
              "Value": "ContratFonds"
            },
            {
              "Key": "nomFournisseur",
              "Value": "LOIS"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "Contrat": [
            {
              "Key": "_type",
              "Value": "ContratEau"
            },
            {
              "Key": "nomFournisseur",
              "Value": "Veolia"
            },
            {
              "Key": "comprisDansLesCharges",
              "Value": false
            },
            {
              "Key": "numeroCompteur",
              "Value": "99Z928"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "Contrat": [
            {
              "Key": "_type",
              "Value": "ContratClimatisation"
            },
            {
              "Key": "nomFournisseur",
              "Value": "CLIM"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "ID": "22",
      "codePdv": 2222222,
      "codeSav": 2222222,
      "contrats": [
        {
          "Contrat": [
            {
              "Key": "_type",
              "Value": "ContratVideosurveillance"
            },
            {
              "Key": "dateDebut",
              "Value": "2020-12-01"
            },
            {
              "Key": "dateFin",
              "Value": "2024-12-01"
            },
            {
              "Key": "nomFournisseur",
              "Value": "E8MA"
            },
            {
              "Key": "dateAutorisationCameras",
              "Value": "2020-12-30"
            },
            {
              "Key": "ligneAlarme",
              "Value": "+33188888489"
            },
            {
              "Key": "nbCamerasAutorisees",
              "Value": 3
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "Contrat": [
            {
              "Key": "_type",
              "Value": "ContratClimatisation"
            },
            {
              "Key": "nomFournisseur",
              "Value": "LACLIM"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm trying to convert JSON format using Jolt Transform but it can't.

Can you Help me please with the Jolt transformation ?

Thanks

I'm trying to convert JSON format using Jolt Transform but it can't.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following spec. You can add another **modify-overwrite-beta** transformation if needed to do type conversion for ***codePdv*** & ***codeSav***.

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "Boutique": {
        "*": {
          "*": "pointsDeVente[&1].&",
          "contrats": {
            "*": {
              "*": {
                "$": "pointsDeVente[&4].&3[&2].contrat[#2].Key",
                "@": "pointsDeVente[&4].&3[&2].contrat[#2].Value"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```